# How to show full column width of polars dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, python-polars

I'm trying to display the full width of column in polars dataframe. Given the following polars dataframe:

```py
import polars as pl 

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'column_1': ['TF-IDF embeddings are done on the initial corpus, with no additional N-Gram representations or further preprocessing', 'In the eager API, the expression is evaluated immediately. The eager API produces results immediately after execution, similar to pandas. The lazy API is similar to Spark, where a plan is formed upon execution of a query, but the plan does not actually access the data until the collect method is called to execute the query in parallel across all CPU cores. In simple terms: Lazy execution means that an expression is not immediately evaluated.'],
    'column_2': ['Document clusterings may misrepresent the visualization of document clusterings due to dimensionality reduction (visualization is pleasing for its own sake - rather than for prediction/inference)', 'Polars has two APIs, eager and lazy. In the eager API, the expression is evaluated immediately. The eager API produces results immediately after execution, similar to pandas. The lazy API is similar to Spark, where a plan is formed upon execution of a query, but the plan does not actually access the data until the collect method is called to execute the query in parallel across all CPU cores. In simple terms: Lazy execution means that an expression is not immediately evaluated.']
})
```

I tried the following:

```py
pl.Config.set_fmt_str_lengths = 200
pl.Config.set_tbl_width_chars = 200
```

The result:

```py
shape: (2, 2)
┌───────────────────────────────────┬───────────────────────────────────┐
│ column_1                          ┆ column_2                          │
│ ---                               ┆ ---                               │
│ str                               ┆ str                               │
╞═══════════════════════════════════╪═══════════════════════════════════╡
│ TF-IDF embeddings are done on th… ┆ Document clusterings may misrepr… │
│ In the eager API, the expression… ┆ Polars has two APIs, eager and l… │
└───────────────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────┘
```

How can I display the full width of columns in a polars DataFrame in Python?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [I don't think there's any way to remove the limits entirely, but you could try setting `-1` or `None`] and iirc they're methods , so: `pl.Config.set_fmt_str_lengths(100)`/`pl.Config.set_tbl_width_chars(200)`

Comment: I tried, didn't work. Using `pl.Config.set_fmt_str_lengths(100)` returns the error message: `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`

Comment: Thanks, updating the library and using `Config.set_fmt_str_lengths(200)` has solved the issue.

Comment: I think you wiped the [original function](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Config.set_fmt_str_lengths.html) and replaced it with `200` when you used `=` so the `TypeError` was raised, but updating/reloading the library should fix it again, as it did. Glad it's working now!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can use [`glimpse`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.glimpse.html):

```
> df.glimpse()

Rows: 2
Columns: 2
$ column_1 <str> TF-IDF embeddings are done on the initial corpus, with no additional N-Gram representations or further preprocessing, In the eager API, the expression is evaluated immediately. The eager API produces results immediately after execution, similar to pandas. The lazy API is similar to Spark, where a plan is formed upon execution of a query, but the plan does not actually access the data until the collect method is called to execute the query in parallel across all CPU cores. In simple terms: Lazy execution means that an expression is not immediately evaluated.
$ column_2 <str> Document clusterings may misrepresent the visualization of document clusterings due to dimensionality reduction (visualization is pleasing for its own sake - rather than for prediction/inference), Polars has two APIs, eager and lazy. In the eager API, the expression is evaluated immediately. The eager API produces results immediately after execution, similar to pandas. The lazy API is similar to Spark, where a plan is formed upon execution of a query, but the plan does not actually access the data until the collect method is called to execute the query in parallel across all CPU cores. In simple terms: Lazy execution means that an expression is not immediately evaluated.
```

Comment: Maybe easier to read if you put linebreak after each value, like: df.limit(10).with_columns(column_1 = pl.col('column_1')+'\n', column_2 = pl.col('column_2')+'\n').glimpse()

Answer (score 4):

Using polars you can do:

```
with pl.Config(fmt_str_lengths=1000):
    print(df)
```

or:

```
with pl.Config(tbl_width_chars=1000):
    print(df)
```

Other options for formatting are here:
https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/config.html

You can also just set the config to stay that way instead of using a `with` context:

`pl.Config(tbl_width_chars=1000)`