# How do I view a polars dataframe without truncating the values?

Tags: python-polars

I have a polars dataframe containing a column called `Notes` that has long text in it. If I simply output that dataframe (i.e. execute `df`) in a Jupyter notebook then the values therein get truncated

[image]

I would like all of the text to be displayed. How do I do that?

To put it another way, I'd like the polars equivalent of [Spark's `show(False)` method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.show.html).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75929721/how-to-show-full-column-width-of-polars-dataframe-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pl.Config.set_fmt_str_lengths`, and set it to a suitably large value:

```py
In [3]: df = pl.DataFrame({'a': ['fdasafsdfassfdafsdfafdsafafdsfsafda', 'fdafdsfafdafdasfdfdaf']})

In [4]: df
Out[4]:
shape: (2, 1)
┌───────────────────────────────────┐
│ a                                 │
│ ---                               │
│ str                               │
╞═══════════════════════════════════╡
│ fdasafsdfassfdafsdfafdsafafdsfsa… │
│ fdafdsfafdafdasfdfdaf             │
└───────────────────────────────────┘

In [5]: pl.Config.set_fmt_str_lengths(100)
Out[5]: polars.config.Config

In [6]: df
Out[6]:
shape: (2, 1)
┌─────────────────────────────────────┐
│ a                                   │
│ ---                                 │
│ str                                 │
╞═════════════════════════════════════╡
│ fdasafsdfassfdafsdfafdsafafdsfsafda │
│ fdafdsfafdafdasfdfdaf               │
└─────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: thx, I posted an answer before I saw yours, but very happy to mark yours as an answer. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I ran:

```py
import polars as pl
pl.Config.set_fmt_str_lengths(900)
pl.Config.set_tbl_width_chars(900)
```

before displaying my dataframe, and that worked:

[image]